# TableView crashing if Empty Array, how to fix?

Tags: uitableview, nsarray

I'm using RestKit to pull data from a web service API, and when the API response with an **empty array for "Image", the `UITableView` crashes**.

I was wondering if an "if statement" would be best to solve the problem?

`cellForRowAtIndexPath`, which works perfectly when there is an Image Array:

```
Images *imageLocal = [apiResponseLocal.images objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *imageURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", imageLocal.url];
```

My best guess that doesn't work for the "if statement"

```
if ([imageURL isEqualToString:@""])
    {
    [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://staticimage.com/to/use/when/no/image/from/api"] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
    }
    else
    {
    [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", imageURL]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"]];
    }
```

I'm not sure if I'm on the right trail trying to solve with an "if statement", or what that actual statement might be.  Any help would be much appreciated!

**EDIT**:
Error & Crash I get when there is no image in the `NSArray` and I try scrolling the TableView toward that particular cell is `"_NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array"`

Comment: Well obviously you're not going to get much of an image from an empty string, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: @HotLicks correct.  I'm trying to place an Image in the ImageView spot if the Image array returned from the API is empty.  You know what I mean?  If I don't get anything back from them, I can put a Image of my own in there.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: The TableView crashes as it stands now saying: "_NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array".  So I need to create some way for if there is no image in the array, for the TableView to not crash because of that specific TableViewCell.  Know what I mean?

Comment: So what line does the crashing noise come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check your array count and handle if it is less than 1 before accessing any index. 
That's the place to do your default no-image image URL logic.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful response!  I will try that out today